# Prove that if product of matrices is singular, one of the matrices is singular.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, proof-writing

I'm having trouble with this proof, it would be much easier to work out the other way it seems.

> Let $A$ and $B$ be square matrices of equal size. Prove that if $\det(AB) = 0 =C$ then either $A$ or $B$ must be singular.

I claimed that because $AB$, denoted $C$, is zero then by rule of matrix product that one has to be zero. This is obviously not a real proof

Comment: Its just that I feel as if this is too simple, that I may have assumed to much rather than built up as I usually would with a proof.  I just said that det(A)det(B)=0   ; if det(a) is zero then we have 0^ndet(a)=0 and same with b but I feel that I may have used fallacious logic, circular reasoning to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative is to use matrix algebra and a proof by contradiction.

Let $AB = C$. Assume, to the contrary, that $C$ is singular (i.e. $C^{-1}$ does not exist) and neither $A$ nor $B$ is singular.

Thus it should be possible to construct both $A^{-1}$ and $B^{-1}$ and therefore $D = B^{-1}A^{-1}$.

Premultiplying by $D$, we get $DAB = I = DC$. Hence $D = C^{-1}$, and an inverse for $C$ exists, which is a contradiction.

Therefore, at least one of $A$ or $B$ has to be singular.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$. If $0 = \det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$, what can you say about $\det(A)$ or $\det(B)$? How does this relate to singularity?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of proving $p\Rightarrow q$, it is almost trivial to prove the equivalent statement $\neg q\Rightarrow \neg p$, that is, if $A$ and $B$ are both nonsingular, then $C$ is nonsingular as well.

Assume that both $A$ and $B$ are nonsingular, that is, there is no nonzero $x$ such that $Ax=0$ or $Bx=0$. Take any $x\neq 0$. Then $Bx\neq 0$ since $B$ is nonsingular. Also, since $A$ is nonsingular, $A(Bx)=Cx\neq 0$. Hence $C$ is nonsingular.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this matrix product: 
$$\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\1&1\end{array}\right]
\left[\begin{array}{cc}1&1\\-1&-1\end{array}\right]=
\left[\begin{array}{cc}0&0\\0&0\end{array}\right]$$